# Time dataType in Visual Studio LightSwitch

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

Is it possible to have a "Time" datatype only in Visual Studio LightSwitch?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help:
Walkthrough: Creating a Business Type Extension
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh290140.aspx